# SharePoint Web Part & Singletons

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint project where we override search box and some other things. We also have a web part page that responds to the search box. All these components should share single configuration. I thought about creating a singleton, but I am not sure how would that ever get cleaned up / removed from the memory / uninstalled.

Any ideas? Any warnings about using singletons in sharepoint? Also, is there a proper way to share an instance of an object between all these componenets?

Edit: I was thinking about a very simple singleton. Configuration only needs to contain 5-20 strings and a dozen integers at most. No complex objects :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the objects being managed by your singleton class are thread-safe there shouldn't be an issue.

**EXAMPLE:**
I have a series of object-calls that were taking a long-time to process (7+ seconds). So, I decided to try using a comet-styled long-polling technique to process them.  As such, I host a service (as a static singleton) in a single thread and process requests using asynchronous HttpHandler's...and it works GREAT!  And because I'm using the service asynchronously it's highly efficient because the calling thread gets released immediately (upon completion of processing the service completes the callback).

**EDIT:**
But your problem of a long processing time still exists, so you still (probably) need an asynchronous solution for the initial fetch. Hows this?  Why not COMBINE the asych-solution with custom-caching?

For various (accessibility) reasons, I save my appSetting's in the database and use a custom-cache for access thereafter.

**EXAMPLE of a Custom Cache:**

```
public enum ConfigurationSection
{
    AppSettings
}

public static class Utility
{
    #region "Common.Configuration.Configurations"

    private static Cache cache = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache;

    public static String GetAppSetting(String key)
    {
        return GetConfigurationValue(ConfigurationSection.AppSettings, key);
    }

    public static String GetConfigurationValue(ConfigurationSection section, String key)
    {
        Configurations config = null;

        if (!cache.TryGetItemFromCache<Configurations>(out config))
        {
            config = new Configurations();
            config.List(SNCLavalin.US.Common.Enumerations.ConfigurationSection.AppSettings);
            cache.AddToCache<Configurations>(config, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15));
        }

        var result = (from record in config
                      where record.Key == key
                      select record).FirstOrDefault();

        return (result == null) ? null : result.Value;
    }

    #endregion
}

namespace Common.Configuration
{
    public class Configurations : List<Configuration>
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS

        public Configurations() : base()
        {
            initialize();
        }
        public Configurations(int capacity) : base(capacity)
        {
            initialize();
        }
        public Configurations(IEnumerable<Configuration> collection) : base(collection)
        {
            initialize();
        }

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES & FIELDS

        private Crud _crud; // Db-Access layer

        #endregion

        #region EVENTS
        #endregion

        #region METHODS

        private void initialize()
        {
            _crud = new Crud(Utility.ConnectionName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Lists one-to-many records.
        /// </summary>
        public Configurations List(ConfigurationSection section)
        {
            using (DbCommand dbCommand = _crud.Db.GetStoredProcCommand("spa_LIST_SecConfiguration"))
            {
                _crud.Db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Section", DbType.String, section.ToString());

                _crud.List(dbCommand, PopulateFrom);
            }

            return this;
        }

        public void PopulateFrom(DataTable table)
        {
            this.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Configuration instance = new Configuration();
                instance.PopulateFrom(row);
                this.Add(instance);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Configuration
    {
        #region CONSTRUCTORS

        public Configuration()
        {
            initialize();
        }

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES & FIELDS

        private Crud _crud;

        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region EVENTS
        #endregion

        #region METHODS

        private void initialize()
        {
            _crud = new Crud(Utility.ConnectionName);
            Clear();
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            this.Section = "";
            this.Key = "";
            this.Value = "";
        }
        public void PopulateFrom(DataRow row)
        {
            Clear();

            this.Section = row["Section"].ToString();
            this.Key = row["Key"].ToString();
            this.Value = row["Value"].ToString();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: How would garbage collector know that an instance needs to be removed? Since singleton has a reference to itself, there is always at lease one, which means object is live. I don't know if matters, really. But, yeah your example is exactly why I want to do this :)

Comment: You want the singleton-service to run continuously in its own thread so it can service calls. The only time you WANT it down is when the application (as a whole) is down...and then it wont matter.  I can post some sample code if you like.

Comment: In the production environment I guess this doesn't matter, because it should always be there. I was asking more from a development standpoint. But, I guess 'project' gets retracted every time I re-deploy, which will probably revoke the assembly and any instances associated with it. I think :)

Comment: Thank you for the input by the way, appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! And...if the application is taken down...everything in the application domain 'goes down' with it.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i wanted to know, just didn't ask the right question :)

Answer (score 4):

If your object is simply configuration (loaded once, and stays read only from that point) I'd not worry about it beeing singleton or about if/when it will be garbage collected (object will not be collected unless you set it to null).

In general in server environment (like SharePoint) you want to make sure 2 things about object before thinking about making it singleton:

- technical aspects (mainly thread safety as pointed by Prisoner ZERO, but also how much memory it uses, if it holds critical resources likle files)
- security aspects - it is extremly easy to leak user's information into singleton object and use it by mistake by some other user. It also possible to cache some information in singleton that one user have access to and than retrive by another user that should not have access to such information.

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be over complicating this and falling into the trap of premature optimisation.

You indicate that your object doesn't have anything more than a couple of dozen strings/integers so presumably you're not doing any expensive setup and therefore is there actually anything to be gained going the singleton approach?

Furthermore the real question here is where these strings/integers are going to be stored - if its hardcoded into your class then you can't update it easily so it would be better to store that config somewhere else.

[Six Ways to to store settings in SharePoint](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Six-ways-to-store-settings-in-SharePoint.aspx)

But IHMO the best way to do this is following the [MSDN SharePoint Guidance Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649628.aspx) which uses the Property Bag storage for their implementation of a hierarchical Configuration Manager which allows you to do things like a farm wide setting but overridden for certain site collections/sites etc.

So in conclusion I personally would

- Implement the config object as a simple object reading values from config manager
- Montor/profile and change to a singleton if necessary

Comment: I wasn't even worried about optimization just yet. The reason why I wanted something like singleton is because there are few components that i want to share some very basic information (no user info or state info). It will most likely be set only handful of times, but accessed here and there. Thank you for the link above, I'll check that out :)